# Making a bipartite graph SCC by adding minimum edges

Tags: algorithm

There's a bipartite graph B(E, V1, V2) such that e = (v1, v2) for e ∈ E, v1 ∈ V1, v2 ∈ V2. Edges in B are directional.

I'd like to make a graph G(E ∪ E', V2 ∪ V2) such that the graph G is strongly-connected component, with minimum sizeof(E'). (sizeof(A) is the number of elements in the set A)
E' doesn't have to be V1 -> V2.

For an example, with V1 = {1, 2, 3} and V2 = {a, b}, there's a bipartite graph B(E, V1, V2) with E = {(1, a), (2, a), (2, b), (3, b)}.
Then E' = {(a, 3), (a, 1), (b, 2)} makes all vertices in G(E ∪ E', V2 ∪ V2) strongly-connected.(whenever I choose vertex pair v1 and v2, there exists a path from v1 to v2)

Can someone give me some idea? Or is there a well-known algorithm about this?

Comment: Must the resulting graph be bipartite?

Comment: A problem with non-bipartite graph can be reduced into the problemwith bipartite graph so it doesn't matter

Answer (score 1):

A theorem by Eswaran and Tarjan says that an acyclic digraph with r sources (i.e., vertices without incoming edges) and s sinks (i.e., vertices without outgoing edges) can be made strongly connected by adding max(r, s) edges (see e.g. [here](http://books.google.de/books?id=mqGeSQ6dJycC&lpg=PA969&ots=xPJLOYdrPe&pg=PA969#v=onepage&q&f=false)). Thus, you need to add max(sizeof(A), sizeof(B)) edges. The book also explains how to find a solution (a simple system of matching up vertices).